# Android Text Selection Terminology

Tags: android, android-emulator, terminology, textselection

How are the two "trapezoids" that appear during text selection (in the emulator) called?

Where can I find more information about how to control them programmatically?

For further clarity, I am attaching a snapshot where you can see the left & right "text-selection trapezoids":

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just call them cursor controllers, or handles.

Comment: Thanks, Googling on [Android "cursor controllers"] yields no information on how to access them programmatically. Where can I find more information on these? Can they be controlled?

Comment: Are these "cursor controllers" the same as in updateCursorControllerPositions() in the following? http://hi-android.info/src/android/widget/TextView.java.html

Comment: Is View.startDrag() the right way to control these handles? Is it possible to position each one of them independently? If so, how? (oops... I just noticed this is only available with API 11. Is there something similar for API 8?)

Comment: You cannot control them programmatically, they are handled by TextView.updateCursorControllerPositions() and startDrag() has nothing to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark--but maybe they're called carets in Webkit?

Comment: Thanks but I can't find any references that use the term "carets" for these. The closest I found were "cursors" and "tags": http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f12/copying-and-pasting-text-from-web-pages-7355/

Answer (score 0):

to be precise ..

In android terminology it is **"SelectionModifierCursorController"**

Answer (score 0):

It would appear based on the [name of the images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19992136/3063884) used to display these handles that they're called Text Select Handles, of which there's a

- Left Text Select Handle;
- Right Text Select Handle; and a
- Middle Text Select Handle (which is just the Left and Right images side-by-side)

The underlying code that manages these is in the three classes that derive from `HandleView` in  `android.widget.Editor`:

- `InsertionHandleView`
- `SelectionStartHandleView`
- `SelectionEndHandleView`