# Remove blue cursor pointer in EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my android application I am using EditText.

In that EditText I don't want to show blue cursor pointer as shown in below figure : -

[image]

Reason for doing so is that user can not enter pasted data in EditText and allow 
user to enter text manualy.

Kindly provide me solution.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : When user clicks on blue pointer hint option is shown.

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910305/android-how-do-i-stop-a-pointer-appearing-below-an-edittext

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to `Edittext` xml...

```
android:cursorVisible="false"
```

If you want to disable the cursor programatically then...

```
editText.setCursorVisible(false)
```

Comment: I don't want to hide cursor.I only want to hide blue cursor indicator below cursor as shown in figure.

Answer (score 1):

> Reason for doing so is that user can not enter pasted data in EditText
>   and allow user to enter text manualy.

Actually you want to disable the copy/paste option in your `EditText`. The blue cursor is a system helper that allows user to move the cursor so quickly. To disable copy/paste you must prevent the context menu appearing by setting a Custom CallBack using `setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback()`

**Solution :** [How to disable copy/paste from/to EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12331404/1329126)

Comment: The cursor still shows with this approach, and clicking on the cursor pointer results in the "Paste" menu appearing, which it appears that the OP wants to avoid.