# What is the name of the EditText selector, and how do you change it? (picture included)

Tags: android, android-edittext, drawable

What is the name of the blue view in the picture below?

[image: Cursor Selector]

I have tried searching "EditText cursor" and "EditText selector", but I am unable to find a name for this drawable.

Also, is it possible to change this drawable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19992136/2636001 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called the Text Select Handle. You can customize it with this handy tool. http://android-holo-colors.com/

in your theme add something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Generated with http://android-holo-colors.com -->
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style parent="@style/_AppTheme" name="AppTheme"/>
<style parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light" name="_AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/apptheme_text_select_handle_left</item>
    <item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/apptheme_text_select_handle_right</item>
    <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/apptheme_text_select_handle_middle</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

edit: spelling

Comment: I think the question was more about how to change it programmatically, not how to generate the asset for it.

Comment: The comment very clearly states it is asking for the name. None the less I have added the required theme xml for changing it.